# Swap key with value in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, key-value

I have an extremely large JSON object structured like this:

```
{A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}
```

I need a function that can swap the values with keys in my object and I don't know how to do it. I would need an output like this:

```
{1 : A, 2 : B, 3 : C, 4 : D}
```

Is there any way that I can do this would manually created a new object where everything is swapped?
Thanks

Comment: are all values numbers and do the numbers repeat? If the values repeat then you wont be able to swap them as they will overwrite the others, unless you change their value to some unique value. There might be a better solution what is the reason for needing the swap?

Comment: @PatrickEvans They're all numbers but they don't repeat. I'm trying to make a basic cipher.

Comment: It's worth noting that a "swap" operation like this is problematic for [at least] two reasons: 1) Values are cast to Strings when they become keys so don't be surprised when you have unexpected "[object Object]" keys. And 2) duplicate values (after cast to String) get overwritten.  #1, at least, can be solved by producing a Map instead of an Object, thusly: `function swap(obj) {return new Map(Object.entries(x).map([k, v] => [v, k]))}`

Comment: `const swap = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r[v]=k, r), {});` Similar approach can be used for arrays where values are positive integers/indices.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
function swap(json){
  var ret = {};
  for(var key in json){
    ret[json[key]] = key;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Example here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bjg6/1/) don't forget to turn on your console to see the results.

---

**ES6** versions:

```
static objectFlip(obj) {
  const ret = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    ret[obj[key]] = key;
  });
  return ret;
}
```

Or using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
static objectFlip(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((ret, key) => {
    ret[obj[key]] = key;
    return ret;
  }, {});
}
```

Or using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
static objectFlip(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((ret, entry) => {
    const [ key, value ] = entry;
    ret[ value ] = key;
    return ret;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` + `Array.prototype.reduce()` is the fastest: https://jsbench.me/y2kzww53oz/1

Answer (score 99):

Now that we have Object.fromEntries:

```js
const f = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(a => a.reverse()))

console.log(
  f({A : 'a', B : 'b', C : 'c'})
) // => {a : 'A', b : 'B', c : 'C'}
```

or:

```js
const f = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]))

console.log(
  f({A : 'a', B : 'b', C : 'c'})
) // => {a : 'A', b : 'B', c : 'C'}
```

(Updated to remove superfluous parentheses - thanks @devin-g-rhode)

Comment: Should be standard way of doing object swap as of Node.js version 12 as well.

Comment: This is the easiest to understand+most beautiful solution. I think you could drop parents on the return value of the arrow callback

Comment: While this is indeed the most elegant solution, it's a little slower than using `Object.entries()` + `Array.prototype.reduce()`: https://jsbench.me/y2kzww53oz/1

Answer (score 66):

you can use [lodash function _.invert](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#invert) it also can use multivlaue

```
 var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1 };

  _.invert(object);
  // => { '1': 'c', '2': 'b' }

  // with `multiValue`
  _.invert(object, true);
  // => { '1': ['a', 'c'], '2': ['b'] }
```

Comment: multiValue is not supported any more

Comment: Since lodash 4: Instead of the setting `multiValue` to `true` you need to use the new method `_.invertBy()`.

Comment: Lodash invert is the fasted implementation by a small margin:
http://jsben.ch/tSjlB
It's interesting looking at the implementation:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/invert.js

Answer (score 56):

Using ES6:

```
const obj = { a: "aaa", b: "bbb", c: "ccc", d: "ddd" };
Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(([a,b]) => ({ [b]: a })))
```

Comment: Seems **the better solution** for nowdays (2019)! Somebody can confirm, is it? Performance good?  Semantic is perfect: we can see that is really a simple "map and swap" solution.

Comment: @peter-krauss, You are welcome to tinker with http://jsben.ch/gHEtn in case I missed something, but a casual comparison between this answer and jPO's answer shows that jPO's for-loop outperforms grappeq's map approach by almost 3 to 1 (at least on _my_ browser).

Comment: I tried it - 30% slower than jPO's on my computer.

Comment: There a comparison with a few more implementation here: http://jsben.ch/tSjlB

Answer (score 39):

Get the keys of the object, and then use the Array's reduce function to go through each key and set the value as the key, and the key as the value.

```js
const data = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
  D: 4
}
const newData = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(obj, key) {
  obj[data[key]] = key;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 31):

In ES6/ES2015 you can combine use of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with the new [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function, an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for a pretty straightforward single statement solution.

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const bar = Object.keys(foo)
    .reduce((obj, key) => Object.assign({}, obj, { [foo[key]]: key }), {});
```

If you're transpiling using the [object spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (stage 3 as of writing this) that will simplify things a bit further.

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const bar = Object.keys(foo)
    .reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [foo[key]]: key }), {});
```

Finally, if you have [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) available (stage 4 as of writing), you can clean up the logic a touch more (IMO).

```
const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const bar = Object.entries(foo)
    .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({ ...obj, [value]: key }), {});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: /Users/markus/Entwicklung/IT1_Beleg/public/es6/vokabeltrainer.js: Unexpected token (53:45)
  51 |     if (btoa) {
  52 |         entries = Object.entries(entries)
> 53 |             .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({...obj, [value]: key}), {});
     |                                              ^

Comment: @Superlokkus my best interpretation of that error output is that you're not transpiling the object spread syntax, and as of today, I don't know of any JavaScript engines that support it natively.

Comment: See @grappeq's solution, seems better (the simplest!).

Answer (score 17):

#### 2021's answer

The concise way by using **ES6** syntax like this.

```js
const obj = {A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[value] = key, acc), {})
);
```

**Explain:**

> `(acc[value] = key, acc)`

Using [**Comma operator (,)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) syntax.

> `The comma operator (,)` evaluates each of its operands (*from left to
> right*) and *returns the value of the last operand*.

Comment: This appears to be the one of the faster implementations (at least in chrome 110):
http://jsben.ch/tSjlB The lodash implementation is just a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement of @joslarson and @jPO answers:
Without ES6 needed, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
Object.keys(foo).reduce((obj, key) => (obj[foo[key]] = key, obj), {});
```

Some may find it ugly, but it's "kinda" quicker as the `reduce` doesn't spread all the properties of the `obj` on each loop.

Comment: Still... jPO's answer outperforms this one by almost 2:1. http://jsben.ch/R75aI  (I know your comment was from long, long ago, but I was commenting on grappeq's answer and figured I'd run your example as well).

Comment: Totally, a for loop remains faster then the `forEach`, `map` or `reduce` methods.
I made this response to have a one-liner solution without the need of es6 and still be relevant in terms of speed/effectiveness.

Comment: Is June 2019 and that is no longer true in latest Google Chrome, the difference is now near non-existent (9:10)

Comment: This appears the most performant of the ES6 variants: http://jsben.ch/HvICq

Answer (score 4):

Using [Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda):

```js
const swapKeysWithValues = 
  R.pipe(
    R.keys,
    R.reduce((obj, k) => R.assoc(source[k], k, obj), {})
  );

const result = swapKeysWithValues(source);
```

Comment: Ramda has `R.invert` and `R.invertObj` which do the same. The first one puts duplicates in a sublist

Answer (score 3):

### Modern JS solution:

```js
const swapKeyValue = (object) =>
  Object.entries(object).reduce((swapped, [key, value]) => (
    { ...swapped, [value]: key }
  ), {});
```

### Typescript:

```
type ValidKey = number | string;

const swapKeyValue = <K extends ValidKey, V extends ValidKey>(
  object: Record<K, V>
): Record<V, K> =>
  Object.entries(object)
    .reduce((swapped, [key, value]) => (
      { ...swapped, [value as ValidKey]: key }
    ), {} as Record<V, K>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let swap = (o,r={})=> Object.keys(o).map(k=> r[o[k]]=k) && r;
```

```js
let obj = {A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4};

let swap = (o,r={})=> Object.keys(o).map(k=> r[o[k]]=k) && r;

console.log(swap(obj));
```

Comment: *note:* `r={}` creates an empty object where the new keys & values are stored. The author could have used `return r` but leveraged `&&r` as a way to keep the code short since `[undefined]&&{}` will always return the object. Overall a pretty clever trick!

Answer (score 1):

With pure Ramda in a pure and point-free style:

```
const swapKeysAndValues = R.pipe(
   R.toPairs,
   R.map(R.reverse),
   R.fromPairs,
);
```

Or, with a little more convoluted ES6 version, still pure functional:

```
const swapKeysAndValues2 = obj => Object
    .entries(obj)
    .reduce((newObj, [key, value]) => ({...newObj, [value]: key}), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest one I came up with using ES6..

```js
const original = {
 first: 1,
 second: 2,
 third: 3,
 fourth: 4,
};


const modified = Object
  .entries(original)
  .reduce((all, [key, value]) => ({ ...all, [value]: key }), {});

console.log('modified result:', modified);
```

Comment: If you are going beyond about 50 or so keys, you will start to see poor performance with this method. Although the spread looks and feels nice, you are creating a new object and assigning all of the keys from the old object every time you go through the loop. You get much better performance by having your reducer function assign to the accumulator:

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = {A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}
    var newData = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){newData[data[key]]=key});
    console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Where does this `object` come from?

Comment: and this is not what `map` is supposed to do, you're using it here like `forEach`

Comment: I never used forEach. I use underscore.js's each function so didn't knew about forEach. Thank you @barbsan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure functional implementation of flipping `keys` and `values` in ES6:

#### TypeScript

```
  const flipKeyValues = (originalObj: {[key: string]: string}): {[key: string]: string} => {
    if(typeof originalObj === "object" && originalObj !== null ) {
      return Object
      .entries(originalObj)
      .reduce((
        acc: {[key: string]: string}, 
        [key, value]: [string, string],
      ) => {
        acc[value] = key
        return acc;
      }, {})
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }
```

#### JavaScript

```js
const flipKeyValues = (originalObj) => {
    if(typeof originalObj === "object" && originalObj !== null ) {
        return Object
        .entries(originalObj)
        .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
          acc[value] = key
          return acc;
        }, {})
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

const obj = {foo: 'bar'}
console.log("ORIGINAL: ", obj)
console.log("FLIPPED: ", flipKeyValues(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function swapKV(obj) {
  const entrySet = Object.entries(obj);
  const reversed = entrySet.map(([k, v])=>[v, k]);
  const result = Object.fromEntries(reversed);
  return result;
}
```

This can make your object, `{A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}`, array-like, so you can have

```
const o = {A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}
const arrayLike = swapKV(o);
arrayLike.length = 5;
const array = Array.from(arrayLike);
array.shift(); // undefined
array; // ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that will swap keys with values but not lose duplicates, if your object is : { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}, it will always return an array in the output :

```
function swapMap(map) {
    const invertedMap = {};
    for (const key in map) {
        const value = map[key];
        invertedMap[value] = invertedMap[value] || [];
        invertedMap[value].push(key);
    }
    return invertedMap;
}
swapMap({a: "1", b: "2", c: "2"})
// Returns => {"1": ["a"], "2":["b", "c"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A simple TypeScript variant:**

```
const reverseMap = (map: { [key: string]: string }) => {
    return Object.keys(map).reduce((prev, key) => {
        const value = map[key];
        return { ...prev, [value]: [...(prev.value || []), key] };
    }, {} as { [key: string]: [string] })
}
```

**Usage:**

```
const map = { "a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"2" };
const reversedMap = reverseMap(map);
console.log(reversedMap);
```

**Prints:**
`{ "1":["a"], "2":["b", "c"] }`

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting answer of @Vaidd4, but using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (instead of [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)):

```
/**
 * Swap object keys and values
 * @param {Object<*>} obj
 * @returns {Object<string>}
 */
function swapObject(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, key) => (Object.assign(r, {
        [obj[key]]: key,
    })), {});
}
```

Or, shorter:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, key) => (Object.assign(r, {[obj[key]]: key})), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {  ...acc, [obj[cur]]: cur };
     }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I'm using:

```
function objSwap(obj, tl = false) {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[v = tl ? v.toLowerCase() : v] = k = tl ? k.toLowerCase() : k, a), {});
}
```

As a bonus: if you need to swap then check some values I added the possibility to lowercase keys and values. Simply you've to set `tl = true`, else if you don't need it ...

```
function objSwap(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[v] = k, a), {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for...of` loop:

```js
let obj = {A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
    
    obj[value] = key

    delete obj[key]

}

console.log(obj) // {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ONE OF THE ES6 WAYS IS HERE**

```
const invertObject = (object) =>Object.entries(object).reduce((result, value) =>  ({...result, [value[1]]: value[0] }), {});

let obj = invertObject({A : 1, B : 2, C : 3, D : 4});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a type-safe way using TypeScript that has not been suggested before. This solution takes two generics that means the return type will be typed as expected. It's faster than doing methods with `.reduce` or `Object.entries`.

```
// Easier way to type `symbol | number | string` (the only valid keys of an object)
export type AnyKey = keyof any;

export function mirror<K extends AnyKey, V extends AnyKey>(
    object: Record<K, V>,
) {
    const ret: Partial<Record<V, K>> = {};

    for (const key in object) {
        ret[object[key]] = key;
    }

    return ret as Record<V, K>;
}
```

Usage:

```
const obj = mirror({
  a: 'b',
  c: 'd',
});

// {b: 'a', d: 'c'}
obj;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's better to do this task by using an npm module, like `invert-kv`.

**invert-kv**: Invert the key/value of an object. Example: {foo: 'bar'} → {bar: 'foo'}

https://www.npmjs.com/package/invert-kv

```js
const invertKv = require('invert-kv');

invertKv({foo: 'bar', unicorn: 'rainbow'});
//=> {bar: 'foo', rainbow: 'unicorn'}
```

Comment: Why is using yet another library better than a one-line solution like @Sc0ttyD suggests, or even a simple for loop?