# How to change the key names to values and values to key names in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

i have array of objects like this

```
[{
    "First Name": "fname",
    "Last Name": "lname"
}, {
    "Root cause": "root"
}, {
    "Comapany Name": "company"
}]
```

i want to convert the above array of objects into like this

```
 [{
    "fname": "First Name",
    "lname": "Last Name"
}, {
    "root": "Root cause"
}, {
    "company": "Comapany Name"
}]
```

please can anybody help me on this.

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23013726/4774345

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap key with value JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013573/swap-key-with-value-json)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var arr = [ {"First Name":"fname", "Last Name":"lname"},
            {"Root cause":"root"},
            {"Comapany Name":"company"}
           ];            
var newArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var obj = {};
    for(key in arr[i]) {
        if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[arr[i][key]] = key;
        }
    }
    newArr.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys in an object. This can be used to access each value in the object.

For example:

```
var newArray = myArray.map(function(obj){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var newObj = {};

  keys.forEach(function(key){
      var newKey = obj[key];
      newObj[newKey] = key;
  });

  return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some library to do that, for example underscore has an invert function http://underscorejs.org/#invert.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't create a new instance, it just inverts the keys in the same object:

```js
var hash = { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2' };

console.log('before', hash)

for (var key in hash) {
  hash[hash[key]] = key;
  delete hash[key];
}

console.log('after', hash)
```

This one creates a new object keeping the original unchanged:

```js
var hash = { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2' };

console.log('before', hash)

var newHash = {};

for (var key in hash) {
  newHash[hash[key]] = key;
}

console.log('new hash inverted', newHash)
```

You can create a function to reuse the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```js
var arr1 =[{"First Name":"fname", "Last Name":"lname"},
{"Root cause":"root"},
{"Comapany Name":"company"}
]

var arr2=[];

for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    
    var obj = {};
    var foo= arr1[i];
    for(var key in foo){
       obj[foo[key]]=key;
    }         
    arr2.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all your array of objects and exchanges object values for object keys:

```js
var a = [{"First Name": "fname", "Last Name": "lname"}, {"Root cause": "root"}, {"Comapany Name": "company"}];

a.forEach(function(o) {
    for (var key in o) {
        o[o[key]] = key;
        delete o[key];
    }
});

console.log(a);
```