# Getting the Key of a Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript

I have a key value pair array in js

```
var tabList = {0:'#description', 1:'#media', 2:'#attributes', 3:'#calendar', 4:'#pricing'}
```

I'm using the keys to get the values in my code

ie. `tabList[2]` returns `#attributes`

I thought I could do the same in reverse to get the key

`tabList[#media]` and have it return `1`

But this doesn't work

How can I fetch the key with only the value as input?

Comment: @csmckelvey - that solution uses Underscore. May not apply here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn The "accepted" solution (which is not even the top upvoted) does, but not all of them do.

Comment: @csmckelvey - yeah - there are a bazillion of them. OP should search.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing this in an array? You could then just use `findIndex()`

Comment: See MDN about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of solutions here [Swap key with value JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013573/swap-key-with-value-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I will flip key with values 1st

```js
var tabList = {0:'#description', 1:'#media', 2:'#attributes', 3:'#calendar', 4:'#pricing'}
let flipped=Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(tabList).map(([k,v]) => ({ [v]: k })))
console.log(flipped);
console.log(flipped['#description']);
```