# From Scores to Leaderboard Sorting dictionary in JS

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary, object

This is probably a classic issue: I have a "dictionary" of scores for each player:

```js
var scores = {
    'player1' : 9,
    'player2' : 3,
    'player3' : 7,
    'player4' : 5
}
```

I want to transform this into a Leaderboard with as key, the position calculated on the number of players and the value, the name of the player:

```js
var leaderboard = {
    1 : 'player1',
    2 : 'player3',
    3 : 'player4',
    4 : 'player2'
}
```

How do I do this in a clean way, without messing too much with temporary lists and dictionaries?
Thank you.

Comment: PS. I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013573/swap-key-with-value-json my issue is different cause the scores for each players can be the same and also I have to transform the keys so that it matches the number of partecipants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the entries of your object (with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) and `.sort()` them to get the order for your leaderboard. Then use `.map()` on your sorted entries to map them to objects, where the object's value is the player, and the index+1 (`i+1`) of the entry is the key. You can then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to build a larger object from this array:

```js
const scores = {
    'player1' : 9,
    'player2' : 3,
    'player3' : 7,
    'player4' : 5
};

const leaderboard = Object.assign(
   {}, 
   ...Object.entries(scores)
       .sort(([,a], [,b]) => b-a)
       .map(([p], i) => ({[i+1]: p}))
);
console.log(leaderboard);
```

**Note:** Your required output is an object with numbered continuous keys. Normally, you would use an array to store this type of data, where the item at position `0` is the "top" leader. For an array output, you simplify the above code to be:

```js
const scores = {
    'player1' : 9,
    'player2' : 3,
    'player3' : 7,
    'player4' : 5
};

const leaderboard = Object.entries(scores)
       .sort(([,a], [,b]) => b-a)
       .map(([p]) => p)

console.log(leaderboard);
```

Comment: I was completely unaware of Object.assign and Object.entries . Cool, Thank you! :D

Comment: @FabioMagarelli no worries. I added some links for further details on both Object methods :)