# Can I fill a object with a for?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to fill and object with a for, but I don't know if it's possible. The code  that I've tried is this:

```
let objecte = {
        0: "a",
        1: "b",
        2: "c",
    };

    let prop = Object.keys(objecte);
    let valor = Object.values(objecte);

    function changePropValues(obj, prop, value){
        let newObj = {};

        for(let i=0;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++){
            newObj = {
                valor[i]: prop[i],
            };
         }
        
        return newObj;

    };

    console.log(changePropValues(objecte,prop,valor
```

But I've this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id

**It's possible fill an object with a for?**

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objecte).map(([a, b]) => [b, a]))`

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013573/swap-key-with-value-json

Comment: There's a [`for..in..`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through the object keys, however, if you got `Object.keys()` extracted, you'd be much better off with something, like: `Object.keys(objecte).reduce((acc, key) => (acc[objecte[key]] = key, acc), {})`, which, I guess, would be more performant, than `Object.entries()`+`Object.fromEntries()`, by the way.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - If you're going to get into microoptimization like that, just use a `for` loop and avoid the unnecessary function calls (and complexity) of using `reduce`. If you're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, `reduce` is just an overcomplicated loop that's easy to get wrong, *especially* when the accumulator value doesn't change (as it doesn't above).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I'm not quite sure, whether you still remembered my comment by the time started replying it. Just to be sure, I'll remind: I recommended to use `for(`-loop (`for..in..`, to be more specific) myself, as opposed to the method OP has used.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - You used the bulk of your comment to suggest `reduce`, and I addressed that. I won't dignify your second comment with a reply

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I'm sure your great experience makes some sort of mind connection to OP to know whether *microoptimisation* is worth it or not. Personally, I wouldn't bet that some function like that may not be used for processing, say, http-requests few hundreds times a second. So just to leave it up to OP to decide, here's a [quick benchmark](https://jsbench.me/jaki5wyrkp/1).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - Synthetic benchmarks are almost completely useless in JavaScript; naive, off-the-cuff ones even less so. They prove nothing here. Engines optimize code aggressively in ways specific to the implementation. Separately: I'm not a fan of snark in technical conversations. It certainly does nothing to advance your point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I didn't  care whether you comment back or not starting from your very first comment, I rather addressed those, who might be tempted to use *plain old* `for(`-loops in inefficient manner just  because they're terrified of `Array.prototype.reduce()` (which brings no value, except great performance and conciseness) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but what you're doing is creating a **new** obejct on each loop iteration. Instead, just add to the object you already have:

```
newObj[valor[i]] = prop[i];
```

(I assume your `value` parameter is called `valor` in your real code, you've changed it in one place but not another.)

---

Note that unless you're using `changePropValues` elsewhere, [Yury's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089139/can-i-fill-a-object-with-a-for/65089171#comment115071509_65089139) for doing `objecte` is nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code inside for statement as follows.

```js
newObj[valor[i]] = prop[i]
```

Comment: When answering you probably noticed that an already exact duplicate was already posted?

Comment: @alexbaes, if it works, can you tick the answer? so that others can know this is correct one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I strongly recommend **not** pushing for OPs to accept answers, and certainly not during the first 15 minutes when they can't. :-) (Also, as Roko pointed out, this just duplicates my answer. That happens sometimes. What I usually do if the other answer was there first is delete mine.)