# How to make Object value to Object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Object named **category**. Here the `property/keys` are in **short-form** and the `value` is in **fullform**. I need to assign Object `property/keys` to Object `value` for a **short time moment**.
Like.

> 'Technology' have to make tech

```js
const category = {
    tech: 'Technology',
    gnr: 'General',
    ent: 'Entertainment',
    sci: 'Science',
}
let a 
a=Object.values(category).map(i=>{
 Object.keys(category).map(j=>{
   i=j
 })
})
console.log(a)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying  to do. Please show an example of the end result you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap key with value in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013573/swap-key-with-value-in-object)

Comment: See this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880502/16848419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const categories = {
    tech: 'Technology',
    gnr: 'General',
    ent: 'Entertainment',
    sci: 'Science',
}

const predicate = 'General';

let match;

for (const category in categories) {
    if (categories[category] === predicate) {
        match = category;
    }
}

console.log(match);
```

Comment: See this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880502/16848419

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = {};
for (let key in category)
{
    a[category[key]] = key;
}
```

or

```js
let a = {};
Object.entries(category).forEach(kv=>a[kv[1]]=kv[0]);
```

Comment: I need this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880502/16848419

Answer (score 0):

Nope! Now after getting match with parameter that I will pass, I need that matching parameter Object Value's `Property/Keys`.
Like,
If **General** Match then I need **gnr**
Here I am getting `'General'` but I need `gnr`

```js
const category = {
    tech: 'Technology',
    gnr: 'General',
    ent: 'Entertainment',
    sci: 'Science',
}
let a 
a=Object.values(category).filter(i=>{
  if(i=='General')  {
return Object.keys(i)
  }
 
})
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Please don't post further questions or problems as answers.